# Custom Class with Enum Property stored in List to be shown in DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, enums

C# project with WinForm with Custom Classes, List<>, enums and Datagridview.

1. I have a class called CStaff, with enums with race, gender, role, wagetype etc.
2. Userinput
3. Then store all the different staff objects in a List<>.
4. List<> gets Saved/Loaded - Not relevant here.
5. Then I bind the List<> to the datagridview with the DataSource property.

   datagrid.datasource = somelist;

This works fine, as it creates columns for all the normal properties for the CStaff object.

But it does not create columns for the enum properties.

Is there a way to force it to create them as well? Or a better way? Also, I would appreciate any links on how to control which properties should be used. At the moment it uses all of them (except the enums).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are using autogenerate columns?

Comment: Please provide the code for your class including the enums.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which properties you want to show and the number of columns of your grid are fixed , you can set AutoGenerateColumns to false.

And manually map the column to the properties of your collection.

You can then use the [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) to display the enum values as a combo-box.